# Add a phrase to the end of each occurrence in Visual Studio Code using Regex starts with and doesn't end with and doesn't contain special sign

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to build an expression which returns all the phrases which start with a given string and not ends with a given string and contain a special character
Example:

Starts with `href="` doesn't contain `.` and not ends with `/`

Matches

```
href="blah/foo"
href="foo"
```

Doesn't match

```
href="blah/foo.css"
href="blah/foo.ico"
href="blah/foo."
href="blah/"
href="blah/foo.css/"
```

I tried to build something like this `(href=\")^((?!.).)|(?!.*\/$)*$`but I'm stuck at the moment.

I also want to be able to add a phrase to the end of each occurrence.

Comment: Try `(href=")(?:[^".]*[^".\/])?(")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/81726f/1))

Comment: It works! How to add something like ".html" to the very end of each occurrence in VS Code?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/81726f/2

Comment: Posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673439/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find**: `(href=")([^".]*[^"./])(")` 
**Replace**: `$1$2.html$3`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/81726f/3)

**Details**

- `(href=")` - Group 1 (`$1`): `href="` substring
- `([^".]*[^"./])` - Group 2 (`$2`): any 0+ chars other than `"` and `.` followed with any char but `"`, `.` and `/`
- `(")` - Group 3 (`$3`): a `"` char.

Test in VS Code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this mate**

```
href="[^.\s]+?(?!\.)[^\/.]"$
```

> Explanantion

- `href="` - Will match exactly `href="`.
- `[^.\s]+?` - Will match anything except `.` and space one or more time (lazy mode).
- `(?!\.)` - Negative look ahead. It checks for `.`.
- `[^\/.]$` - Checks for end of string should not contain `/` or `.`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GM7HpV/3)